# How to unmarshal the XML with unknown child elements in java?

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling

How can be a XML with unknown child elements unmarshaled in java?
Please find the sample xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <date>2015-09-01</date>
    <hour>08:30</hour>
    <to>Tom</to>
    <from>Jack</from>
    <data>
        <id>123</id>
        <value>
            <name>test value</name>
            <description>test description</description>
        </value>
    </data>
</root>
```

Comment: You could use a SAX Parser.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've created a java object, in this case Root.java, with appropriate fields, you could do:

```
JAXBContext context = new JAXBContext(Root.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

Root root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File(yourXmlFilePathHere));
```

As I understand it, this should update only the fields specified by the xml file. So if you don't specify anything for `<data></data>` for example, I don't think there'll be an issue.